# What id of the item we need to put when adding item in SQLite through Room? Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a todo list app that use room for storing data.

My data class looks like this

```
@Entity
data class ToDoItem(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val description: String
)
```

When I add the new item in the list I am making this way

```
  viewModel.addItem(ToDoItem(0,title.toString(), description.toString()))
```

So it works fine. My question is why I can always send `0` as a primary key value? Why I don't have to get last item primary key value and send it as a parameter? How it works? Why I can always send hardcoded `0` and it works without any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why I can always send 0 as a primary key value?

- The exact reason depends upon how you are inserting rows. If using an `@Insert` annotated function, then the `onConflict=` value.

> Why I don't have to get last item primary key value and send it as a parameter?

- because, as explained below, a combination  of an integer type such as `Int` and the `@primayKey` annotation is an SQLite special case that allows generation of the value. Again this depends upon how you are inserting the rows.

> How it works? and Why I can always send hardcoded 0 and it works without any issues?

- as explained below

**Explanation**

With SQLite, which is the database around which Room is a wrapper. The combination of a column type of `INTEGER` and `PRIMARY KEY` is a special case scenario where the column is an alias of a special column named **rowid**. The **rowid** exists for all tables (except for some special cases such as `WITHOUT ROWID` tables, which Room doesn't cater for).

If no value is specified for **rowid** then SQLite ascertains the value to be assigned (typically 1 greater than the last rowid for that table). There is a variation in that the use of the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, which can only be used if `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is specified. This implements a rule that the **rowid** must be greater than any **rowid** assigned (even if the row has been deleted).

`AUTOINCREMENT` is inefficient as it requires a table (sqlite_sequence), that has to be searched and updated for any row inserted into the table that has `AUOINCREMENT` coded.

In Room specifying `autoGenerate = true` results in the use of AUTOINCREMENT.

Room, at compile time, looks at the `@Entity` annotated classes that are in the list of entities defined in the `@Database` annotation and uses members/fields in the class to determine the table's definition.

If a member/field is annotated with `@PrimaryKey` AND the type of the member/variable is an integer type such as Long, Int then it will be an alias of the **rowid**.

As such Room has to decide when and when not to apply a value or not when inserting a row.

If the value is null (Long? Int?) then Room knows not to apply a value and doesn't.

However, as in your case, as you have `Int=0` as opposed to `Int?=null` then IF `autogenerate` is true then Room assigns no value and the value is generated. Without `autoGenerate=true` then Room assigns 0 (in the case of `Int=0`) and every id would be 0 if the value isn't set to another value. As `PRIMARY KEY` implies `UNIQUE` then only 1 row can have a **rowid** with a value of 0 and a `UNIQUE` **conflict** occurs.

SQLite caters for handling of some conflicts giving some control as to how the conflict is handled. That is the `INSERT` can be followed by the keyword `OR` and an action which can be:-

- `ABORT` (the default)
- `ROLLBACK` (which will ABORT if not in a specified transaction)
- `FAIL`
- `IGNORE` (the conflict is ignored)
- `REAPLCE` (the conflict is ignored after overwriting the existing row)

Room allows you to specify one of these by using the `onConflict` parameter when using the `@Insert` annotation.

So how your repeated insertion of an id with **0**, as you do not have `autogenerate=true` depends upon the `onConflict` parameter.

If it is `IGNORE` (`onConflict=OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE`) then only the first row is inserted.

If it is `REPLACE` (`onConflict=OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`) then each subsequent insertion overwrites the previous row.

---

**Suggestion**

Even though it is contrary to the examples that Room provides. It is suggested that

- a) that integer primary keys use a type of **`Long`**. The reason being:-

  - SQLite's `INTEGER` caters for a 64 bit signed integer, so in theory an Int is not large enough. SQLite will in fact store the value in as little space as needed (as low as 1 byte).
  - the **id** returned when inserting using an `@Insert` annotated function is a Long or an array of Long's, so there is no need to use the `Int`'s `toInt` method. *(see link to demo for example of retrieving the id)*.
- b) that `Long?=null` is used, so that by default an id is generated.
- c) that `autoGenerate=true` is not used, unless strictly needed.

  - typically the id will be greater, that until the 9223372036854775807th has been inserted, when

    - if `AUTOINCREMENT` (aka `autoGenerate=true`) is specified then an SQLITE_FULL error will result.
    - otherwise attempts will be made to return an unused value rather than an error.

      - 9223372036854775807's rows is beyond the storage capacity of any existing storage device.

You may wish to refer to

- [**`AUTOINCREMENT`**](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)
- [The **`ON CONFLICT`** Clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)
- [A recent answer that demonstrates using `Int=0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757679/android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-unique-constraint-failed-mod/73758918#73758918)

Answer (score -1):

Lok at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916388/android-room-inserts-duplicate-entities) regarding how Room handles duplicates. From your code, it looks like you're either creating duplicate entries, all with the ID of `0`, or you just keep updating the same entry every time.

What happens when you try to retrieve all the entries? Specifically, are you getting multiple entries with the `id=0`? If not, does it look like there's just one entry with the `id=0`? Or is it auto-generating the IDs for you?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the autoGenerate property

Your primary key annotation should be like this:

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

For more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate()